# Update to 10.15 Catalina even though Big Sur is released

Tags: catalina, software-update, big-sur

I'm still on 10.14. I would like to work with Xcode 12 now, which only supports 10.15+. Yet, no direct download for 10.15 can be found anymore.

I do not want to make the move to macOS 11 Big Sur yet as it seems too unstable.

Comment: Apple has an article how to install older version. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683 Maybe your search terms didn’t match what your search engine requires to find the article?

Comment: @bmike - I've added that as a bit of a TL:DR to the top of the canonical, as it's getting a bit long in the tooth these days ;)

Comment: I was going to move the name to the link to the top as soon as I was at a computer - harder to cut/paste on iPad without my mouse / keyboard attached. Thanks! And thanks Fabian - having a clear question point to the main question is very helpful for the site.

Comment: @bmike Yeah I think I was missing "older" as a search term. I googled queries with 10.15 and catalina but all referred to the time it was released :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is still in the App Store, even though a search did not find it.

Direct link: https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314

Instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683